# Navigation menu dropdown top level doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu with top level and two sub levels. The thing is that the sub levels work just fine, I can click on them and it takes me to the page I selected. The problem is with the top level, when I hover over it it displays the submenus but when I click on it it doesn't take me to the page.

```js
var menu_Sub = $(".menu-has-sub");
var menu_Sub_Li;
$(".mobile-device .menu-has-sub").find(".fa:first").removeClass("fa-angle-right").addClass("fa-angle-down");
menu_Sub.click(function() {
  if ($(".header").hasClass("mobile-device")) {
    menu_Sub_Li = $(this).parent("li:first");
    if (menu_Sub_Li.hasClass("menu-opened")) {
      menu_Sub_Li.find(".sub-dropdown:first").slideUp(function() {
        menu_Sub_Li.removeClass("menu-opened");
        menu_Sub_Li.find(".menu-has-sub").find(".fa:first").removeClass("fa-angle-up").addClass("fa-angle-down");
      });
    } else {
      $(this).find(".fa:first").removeClass("fa-angle-down").addClass("fa-angle-up");
      menu_Sub_Li.addClass("menu-opened");
      menu_Sub_Li.find(".sub-dropdown:first").slideDown();
    }
    return false;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
menu_Sub_Li = menu_Sub.parent("li");
menu_Sub_Li.hover(function() {
  if (!($(".header").hasClass("mobile-device"))) {
    $(this).find(".sub-dropdown:first").stop(true, true).fadeIn("fast");
  }
}, function() {
  if (!($(".header").hasClass("mobile-device"))) {
    $(this).find(".sub-dropdown:first").stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeOut("fast");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-menu">
  <ul class="nav-menu-inner">
    <li>
      <a href="connexion">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="menu-has-sub" href="about-us">About us <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <!-- Dropdown -->
      <ul class="sub-dropdown dropdown">
        <li>
          <a class="menu-has-sub" href="clients-case-studies">Clients and Case Studies</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- End Dropdown -->
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please also post your css, it's key to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises in your `return false` call at the end of your first if statement:

```
menu_Sub.click(function () {
if ($(".header").hasClass("mobile-device")) {
    menu_Sub_Li = $(this).parent("li:first");
    if (menu_Sub_Li.hasClass("menu-opened")) {
...
}
else {
    return false;  // this prevents the default click action from occuring
}
});
```

What you are saying here is basically, if I click on the `.menu-has-sub` link and it doesn't have a `.mobile-device` class, I want it to `return false`.

That essentially means `event.preventDefault()` - read this SO answer for a great explanation [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

But that seems to be your problem, be careful when preventing the default action on links, if you want them to go somewhere.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BrettEast/z7bbLcx2/2/) with the line commented out.

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much! I'll take a look at the link.

Comment: Thanks @dileoh - if that was able to answer your question, I'd love it if you could upvote and accept the answer